# SparkR: unable to create the Spark session

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to run SparkR on a Windows machine.

I ran the following command in R Studio:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
```

this ran successfully.

I am facing error while creating spark session:

```
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: C:\Users\p2\Downloads\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Java version check failed. Please make sure Java is installed and set JAVA_HOME to point to the installation directory.simpleWarning: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\java -version' had status 1
```

I have installed Java 8 and have also set `JAVA_HOME`.

Still, the problem is not solved. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://www.alfredogmarquez.com/2018/05/15/spark-installation-on-windows/

Comment: @abhiieor tried the blog steps, still stuck in JAVA issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my issue resolved. The issue was with my **JAVA_HOME** path, it was failing because `Program Files` contains space.

I copied the java folder from `Program Files` to a different folder : `C:\\Users\\p2\\Downloads\\java\\jre1.8.0_171` and set it as `JAVA_HOME` in `R` program.

> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\Users\p2\Downloads\java\jre1.8.0_171")

and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got sparklyr to connect in my Windows laptop when I set the Java Home and SPARK_HOME

```
java_path <- normalizePath('C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66')
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME=java_path)
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

After setting the JAVA_HOME

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
spark_path = sc$spark_home
spark_disconnect(sc)

Sys.setenv(
SPARK_HOME=spark_path
)
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = 
"2g"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to move the java folder to downloads. The following code worked for me.

```
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171"
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171")
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
[1] "C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jre1.8.0_171"
```

The symbol `~1` replaces the space on the path. I hope it works like me.

Comment: I tried your solution, i am getting this error: `running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\java -version' had status 1`

Comment: Try the java jdk file `Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_151")` not with the jre1, it should be stored in the following path `C:\Program Files\Java\`

Answer (score 0):

I observed one more thing, to set path upto JRE or JDK folder. Don't include Bin anymore. With new sparkR version, it works for me...